# I need help in python code analysis

Tags: python

I have to implement a bioinformatics algorithm on Java over cloud.  I have been given Python code for the same.  I know Java and Hadoop quite well;

However, I have no knowledge in Python. I am looking for a tool so I can analyze the Python code, understand the algorithm and prepare a pseudo code for implementing it in Java. I already looked for some dependency analyzer; however, it didn't help much.

Is my approach wrong?  Do I have to learn Python to do this task?

I am willing to work hard on this project, I need the direction. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Python really isn't a hard language to learn.

Comment: @alpha123 -- you're right about that, but it does have a number of nuances which can be a little tricky if you don't know how they work ...

Comment: @mgilson definitely, but unless the algorithm is very complex he's not likely to run into one of those.

Comment: @alpha123 -- That very much depends on how immersed in python the person writing the code is.  I frequently write things like `next(a for a in foo if condition(a))` to pull the first element from an iterator which matches a particular condition.  That's reasonably idiomatic, but you could easily spend 30 minutes googling around to try to figure out what that statement means if you're not used to generator expressions and what the `next` statement does, etc.  That said, python is great (and pretty easy to learn the basics).  My vote is "Just learn python" (and be glad you did :)

Comment: +1 to learning basics of python, it's an easy language and if you can't understand something you can always ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand a program written in python, you should learn python. This will probably be the easiest way, if there is no other description of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a very easy language to learn, plus you barely will have to learn much to just read an algorithm. Python reads like pseudocode.

The trick is, which version of Python to learn? There are two major versions: Python 2 and Python 3. Code written for Python 2 will probably not run in Python 3 and vice versa. So figure out which one you're dealing with first. Probably the best way to find out is ask the person you got the Python code from.

The official Python tutorials are pretty easy to follow, and I'd recommend you start with those.

- Python 2: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/
- Python 3: http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/

Don't worry about learning a new language. Python is very easy to learn, and you only need to learn a small part of it. I learned almost all the syntax in an evening.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, you guys are amazing such a quick response.

Comment: I really appreciate it. Algorithm is complex as it deals with statistics. I would take help again if I get stuck. Thanks again really appreciate it. Have great time.

Comment: @user1772218 no problem! Follow the Python tutorials I linked to, and if you get stuck, feel free to ask here on StackOverflow!

Comment: @alpha123: I would definitely agree that a lot of the core language would be pretty familiar to someone that knows other C-like languages. But things like iterators and comprehensions are less well-known outside python (even though they're powerful and incredebly useful). But the standard library (which is a large part of the usefulness of python) is quite large. Not to mention that a complex algorithm enploying statistics might as well use numpy/scipy adding extra complexity.

Comment: Scipy is used.. OK so I assume it won't be easy.. I should start right away. Thanks guys.   Really appreciate your evaluation. You guys are awesome.